# LibGDX - Stage.setViewport(new Viewport()) black screen

Tags: java, libgdx, render, viewport

For organization's sake, I use multiple scenes for my game and rather than having each scene have a constructor that receives a Viewport (my game is scalable), I would like to set each stage's viewport separate of the constructor, then after the viewport is set, add the actors. In the main class, it would happen like this:

```
public void setStage(Stage s)
{
    if(currentStage != null)
        currentStage.dispose();
    currentStage = s;
    currentStage.setViewport(view);
}
```

To make this go fluidly, each stage has an init method that is called within an overriden setViewport:

```
@Override
public void setViewport(Viewport v)
{
    super.setViewport(v);
    init();
}
```

However, all this gives me is a black screen... I have tried updating the camera and viewport, but no avail (note that the actors are having their render methods called).

Why am I getting this black screen and how do I fix it? If it's not possible I'll just revert to using the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void setViewport(Viewport v)
    {
        super.setViewport(v);

        this.getViewport().update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);

        Camera c = this.getViewport().getCamera();
        c.position.set(c.viewportWidth/2, c.viewportHeight/2, 0);

        init();
    }
```

This works, but you should also be able to update the Viewport like that at the begin of your application, if you continue to use the same one. I set the position like that instead of centering because some of my Stages will be larger than the screen.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly you want to do this:

```
Stage stage1 = new Stage();
stage1.getViewport().update(width, height);
```

rather than this:

```
Stage stage1 = new Stage (new StretchViewport(width, height)); // It doesn't have to be   StretchViewport
```

In the first case (what you are trying to do) a ScalingViewport will be costructed automatically for you with dimensions of the Gdx.graphics and an orthographic camera and acts like a StretchViewport. Why not using the second case directly where you pass the viewport you want. You can always alter your viewport whenever you want by calling `stage1.getViewport().update(width, height);`

or by calling `stage1.setViewport(width, height, false);` in older Libgdx versions.

Viewport has changed recently so if you can extend Viewport class to Override the update method  maybe you can achieve what you want:

```
public class ViewportExtendClass extends StretchViewport{

public ViewportExtendClass(float worldWidth, float worldHeight) {
    super(worldWidth, worldHeight);
}

@Override
public void update (int screenWidth, int screenHeight, boolean centerCamera) {
    super.update(screenWidth, screenHeight, centerCamera);
    // DO YOUR INITIALIZATION HERE
}
```

}

From your main class you create new stage :

```
Stage stage1 = new Stage (new ViewportExtendClass (width, height));
```

and then you call :

```
stage1.getViewport().update(width, height);
```

Like this you can alter stage viewport and re initialize your assets.

Comment: That is more or less what I did, except that I overrode the setViewport method in my stage (I did it once in a class extending from stage and then all my states extend that class). Update only needs to be called once if you create your own viewport.